# efibootmgr: what if I remove all the non-manual entries?

Tags: uefi

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Arch Linux    HD(1,GPT,bebb1ca0-2911-46cd-b95d-8c7576d50371,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\arch\vmlinuz-linux)r.o.o.t.=.U.U.I.D.=.a.a.a.d.0.c.c.9.-.3.3.e.0.-.4.e.3.9.-.9.5.4.7.-.8.b.1.a.7.a.9.9.3.4.7.5. .r.w. .i.n.i.t.r.d.=./.E.F.I./.a.r.c.h./.i.n.i.t.r.a.m.f.s.-.l.i.n.u.x...i.m.g.
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,bebb1ca0-2911-46cd-b95d-8c7576d50371,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* EFI USB Device (KingstonDataTraveler 2.0) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x282bad86,0xa4,0x20000)RC
Boot0006* EFI USB Device 1 (USB DISK 2.0)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(2,MBR,0xef2cc5f3,0x800800,0xfa000)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

0002 option was added by mint and is certainly unneeded, but what about all those options below, like EFI Network and others? If I remove them, will it affect my computer's functionality or is it safe? Would I have to re-add them manually or would they re-add themselves automatically if I connect EFI-bootable device?

Comment: I don't know, but I've removed all entries I didn't create myself.